# Ruby (File.exist? - FileTest.exist?) on S3 object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can someone help me with recommending convention to call File.exist? or FileTest.exist? on an AWS S3 object in Ruby/Rails?

I'm storing the object in a string ie:

```
aws_photo = "https://s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/examplesite/photo.JPG"
```

Calling the above methods on the string all yield a FALSE return by Ruby.

```
File.exist?(aws_photo) => false
```

I've also tried:

```
FileTest.exist? and File.exist?(aws_photo.url) - (aws_photo.path)
```

to no avail...

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using carrierwave or some other uploader?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that the file path is correct?

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla: i'm pretty sure that `File.exist?` doesn't work for _remote_ files. :)

Comment: @AlejandroMontilla - yes, the file path is correct. A simple cut/paste in new tab renders the image. 

I can check the object with AWS-SDK gem but just wanted to see if there's a Ruby convention that I should know of. Thanks!

Comment: PS @SergioTulentsev - if that's the case, I will note it as such and carry on. Thanks!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev is right, woks only on local files.